# SQL Server Back End, Front End?

Tags: sql, database, frontend

Ok so this is my first question on this site so please bear with me.

My problem is that our company is currently changing from access to an SQL database back end and I was given the job to design a front-end for non programmer users to just pull pre-defined queries or build a query of their own by just selecting the fields they want (dynamic query).

What I want to know is what would be the simplest way to go about doing this due to the fact that I have a some programming background but I wouldn't say I'm an advanced programmer.

I've done some searching over the last couple days and came across things such as Ruby on Rails and phpMyAdmin however before I take on the task of learning how to program with these tools I want to know for sure if I am going in the right direction before wasting my time on a pointless endeavor.

I've seen similar questions even on this site however none truly gave the answer I was looking for; any help will be much appreciated.

Also would it be easier to make this web-based?

Comment: If your users already know access, you can link your access database to SQL in the back end.

Comment: Some other options: Excel with MS Query , devart's query builder, db visualiser

Comment: SAP Business Objects Web Intelligence is something you'll want to take a look at. Simple interface for front end users, mostly drag and drop!

Comment: The company wants to be more "ambitious" they do not want to use excel nor access they want to be able to do this through web.